# How do I load a jar dynamically/at runtime in a graal VM native image?

Tags: java, native, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, dynamic-class-loaders

- I have a particular compile dependency, let's say
  **clientData_V1.jar**. I build a native image out of my Spring boot app using Graal VM 22.3. When I actually want to execute the native
  image that I generated, I want to replace the **clientData_V1.jar**
  that I used in creating the native image with **clientData_V2.jar**.
  Is this possible in a native image? Earlier when I was on OpenJDK I
  was using a Spring's **PropertiesLauncher** to accomplish this.
- I was sifting through the documentation and [on Dynamic features and accessing resources](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/dynamic-features/) which seemed a bit relevant for my use case but I'm not sure this will allow me to read a jar from the local file system and replace the one that is already a part of the native image.

Any help would be appreacited, Thanks.

Comment: Native images do not include bytecode interpreter so they cannot load classes from jars at runtime. You'll need to have the V2 jar available at image build time (but then, you don't need the V1 jar at all)

Comment: So there isn't way to do this directly? An indirect approach that I'm considering is converting the required client data jar methods to native methods with entrypoints, create a shared library from this jar and load it during Runtime using System.load("my.so"). Does this make sense?

Comment: You can even use GraalVM to compile the client jar to a shared library (see `--shared` option). This way, you won't need to convert Java to native methods. But then, again, why not compile the app together with the client jar into one static image?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [espresso](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/java-on-truffle/) which is a Java-as-a-foreign-language embedding framework for Java. Never tried it, but it can probably be compiled into a native image and provide capability to interpret bytecodes.